# Iterate Over an Array

Tags: javascript

In this exercise, you'll use the for....of loop to iterate over an array and to iterate over an object's own properties.

Step 1. You are given an array of dairy products:

```
var dairy = ['cheese', 'sour cream', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'ice cream', 'milkshake']
```

Create a function called logDairy. Within it, console log each of the items in the dairy array, using the for...of loop.
The expected output should be:

```
cheese
sour cream
milk
yogurt
ice cream
milkshake
```

Step 2. You are given the following starter code:

```
const animal = {

canJump: true

};

const bird = Object.create(animal);

bird.canFly = true;

bird.hasFeathers = true;
```

Create a function called `birdCan`, within it, loop over the bird object's properties and console log each one, using the for...of loop. Remember, you need to console log both the key and the value of each of the bird object's properties.

Step 3. Using the same starter code as in task 2, create a function called `animalCan` and within it, loop over all the properties in both the bird object and its prototype - the animal object - using the for...in loop.

```js
// Task 1

function logDairy() {

  const logDairy = ['cheese', 'sour cream', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'ice cream', 'milkshake'];
  for (let i = 0; i < logDairy.length; i++) {
    console.log(logDairy[i])
  }

}
logDairy();
// Task 2
function birdCan() {
  const animal = {
    canJump: true
  };

  const bird = Object.create(animal);

  bird.canFly = true;

  bird.hasFeathers = true;

  for (prop of Object.keys(bird)) {
    console.log(prop + ":" + bird[prop])
  }
}
birdCan();

// Task 3
function animalCan() {
  const animal = {
    canJump: true
  };
  const bird = Object.create(animal);

  bird.canFly = true;

  bird.hasFeathers = true;

  for (prop in animal) {
    console.log(prop);
  }

  for (prop in bird) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
}
animalCan();
```

I have passed task 1 but not 2nd and 3rd

result

Passed: Console logged expected values for logDairy
FAILED: Console logged expected values for birdCan - returned canFly:truehasFeathers:true but expected canFly: truehasFeathers: true
FAILED: Console logged expected values for animalCan - returned canJumpcanFlyhasFeatherscanJump but expected canFly: truehasFeathers: truecanJump: true

tell me where did i go wrong?

Comment: Can you spot the difference between `canFly:true`, and `canFly: true`?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Task 1

function logDairy() {

  const logDairy = ['cheese', 'sour cream', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'ice cream', 'milkshake'];
  for (let i = 0; i < logDairy.length; i++) {
    console.log(logDairy[i])
  }

}
logDairy();
// Task 2
function birdCan() {
  const animal = {
    canJump: true
  };

  const bird = Object.create(animal);

  bird.canFly = true;

  bird.hasFeathers = true;

  for (prop of Object.keys(bird)) {
    console.log(prop + ":" + " " + bird[prop])
  }
}
birdCan();

// Task 3
function animalCan() {
    const animal = {
        canJump: true
    };

    const bird = Object.create(animal);

    bird.canFly = true;

    bird.hasFeathers = true;
    
    for (const prop in bird) {//loops over all properties in the object,  including the prototype's properties.
        console.log(prop + ":" + " " + bird[prop]);
    }
}

    animalCan();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
var dairy = ['cheese', 'sour cream', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'ice cream', 'milkshake']

const logDairy = ()=>{
  for(const item of dairy){
    console.log(item);
  }
}

logDairy();


const animal = { canJump: true};

const bird = Object.create(animal);
bird.canFly = true;
bird.hasFeathers = true;

const birdCan = ()=>{
  for(const prop of Object.keys(bird)){//using for of just iterate of object's own properties
    console.log(prop, bird[prop]);
  }
}
birdCan();

function animalCan() {
    for(const prop in bird){//loops over all properties in the object,  including the prototype's properties.
      console.log(prop, bird[prop]);
  }
}
animalCan();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Step:1
var dairy = ['cheese', 'sour cream', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'ice cream', 'milkshake']
// function to show the output
function logDairy(product){
console.log(product)
}
// for of loop to iterate over the array
for(product of dairy){
logDairy(product)
}
//Step:2
// in this step the condition was to loop over the object using for of loop
// for of loop can only be used on arrays
// so we will create an array or keys from the object using Object.key(obj) and use for of loop on the object,
// we will receive a single key for each iteration, the key will be passed down to function as param
// then we will use bracket notation to find the value of the key.
// animal object
const animal = {
canJump: true
};
// sending obj as param
animalCan(animal)
//bird object
const bird = Object.create(animal);
bird.canFly = true;
bird.hasFeathers = true;
// sending object as param
animalCan(bird)
// function to show key value from object
function birdCan(prop){
console.log(`${prop}: ${bird[prop]}`)
}
// for of loop to iterate over the keys array
for(const prop of Object.keys(bird)){
// sending keys to function as param
birdCan(prop)
}
//Step:3
// using for in loop we can loop over the object sent as param and iterate over it to genrate results
// animalCan function to loop over the object sent as param
function animalCan(param){
for(const prop in param){
console.log(`${prop}:${param[prop]}`)
}
}
```

this should be enough to understand

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Task 1
function logDairy() {
    var dairy = ['cheese', 'sour cream', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'ice cream', 'milkshake']
    for (word of dairy) {
        console.log(word)
    }
}
logDairy()
console.log();

// Task 2
const animal = {
  canJump: true
};

const bird = Object.create(animal);
bird.canFly = true;
bird.hasFeathers = true;

function birdCan() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(bird)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
}

birdCan();
console.log();

// Task 3

function animalCan() {
  for (const key in bird) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${bird[key]}`);
  }
}

animalCan();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Successful Passed Test

```
function logDairy() {

  const logDairy = ['cheese', 'sour cream', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'ice cream', 'milkshake'];
  for (let dairy of logDairy) {
    console.log(`${dairy}`);
  }

}
logDairy();
// Task 2
const animal = {
    canJump: true
  };
  const bird = Object.create(animal);
  bird.canFly = true;
  bird.hasFeathers = true;

function birdCan() {
  for (let value of Object.keys(bird)) {
  
    console.log(`${value}: ${bird[value]}`)
    // Output Like 
    // canFly: true
    //hasFeathers: true
    
  }
}
birdCan();

function animalCan() {

  for (let value in bird)
 {     
   console.log(`${value}: ${bird[value]}`);
    }
}
animalCan();
```

*Passed: Console logged expected values for logDairy*

*Passed: Console logged expected values for birdCan*

*Passed: Console logged expected values for animalCan*

Comment: Expected Output follow  to our code output console and relate to README.md file with matching  , and loop variable declare important  for pass test